# Convert a dataframe with string representations of lists to a dataframe with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe somehow got messed up. There are 2 columns in it that were supposed to contain lists, but now they contain strings of lists:

```
id.       array

72        [ 2.2545414  -0.8302277  -9.557333    1.944972...
73        [ 3.0519443   1.2425094  -1.7121094   0.394222...
74        [ 2.9175313   1.0301533  -1.0083416   1.545938...
77        [-8.521629    3.2176793   2.5869853   1.399137...

id.       names_arrays

72        ['T恤', '外套', '夹克', '衬衣', '领带', '衬衫', '围巾', '粉色...
73        ['济科', '外画', '段萍', '泰舍', '萎缩性', '祝丹妮', '大京', '...
74        ['秀场', '时装周', '时装秀', '舞台', '红毯', '时装设计', '复古风'...
```

You can't see it on the dataframe itself, but when I print:

```
np.array(df['array'][:1])[0]
```

I get

```
'[ 2.2545414  -0.8302277  -9.557333    1.9449722   3.7186048   5.790459\n  0.07255215  1.3358237  -2.9177604   4.03371    -1.4177471  -1.2400303\n  2.5485678   1.0194561   0.14744097 -1.0286134   2.1207867  -1.6046501\n  3.640595   11.30236     0.98157316 -4.8968134  -0.80825585 -2.9547403\n  8.363517   -0.7563907   0.590438    0.14872111  0.28678164 -4.1656523\n  0.21350707  2.7396295  -0.86256826 -3.0678177  -2.2119153  -3.3205476\n  1.7437696  -3.5955458  -3.811455   -2.4635699   2.3464768   3.774634\n]'
```

And the other column:

```
np.array(df['names_arrays'][:1])[0]
>>> "['T恤', '外套', '夹克', '衬衣', '领带', '衬衫', '围巾', '粉色', '纽扣', '球鞋']"
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list) to be useful for the `names_arrays` column

```
literal_eval(np.array(df['names_arrays'][:1])[0])
>>> ['T恤', '外套', '夹克', '衬衣', '领带', '衬衫', '围巾', '粉色', '纽扣', '球鞋']
```

But 1. I'm not sure how to do it for the entire dataframe (rather than a single row)
and 2. this doesn't work for the column `array` as it doesn't have commas in between the numbers, and also there are `\n` in between sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `applymap` on a custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('[ 2.2545414  -0.8302277  -9.557333    1.944972]', "['T恤', '外套', '夹克', '衬衣', '领带', '衬衫', '围巾', '粉色']"), ('[ 3.0519443   1.2425094  -1.7121094   0.394222]', "['济科', '外画', '段萍', '泰舍', '萎缩性', '祝丹妮', '大京']")]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['array', 'names_arrays'])

def fix_lists(text):
    return text.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', ' ').replace("'", '').split()

df = df.applymap(fix_lists)
```

`df['array'][0][0]` will return 2.2545414, and `df['names_arrays'][0][0]` T恤.

Comment: This seems really close. The issue I mentioned with the `array` column is that there are no commas between the numbers so I can't use `literal_eval` (I got an error when I did try)

Comment: I see! I have updated the answer with a solution that first removes redundant characters and then simply creates a list by splitting on whitespace.